# Why do hidden comments from excel file are automatically seen in libre office spreadsheet?

Tags: libreoffice

Hidden comments from microsoft excel file are automatically seen in libre office spreadsheet. I do not know what command to use and just manually hide one by one the comments.

Comment: what version LO? 4.1 seems to have this: fdo#39454:  http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/libreoffice/2012-December/042876.html